# New to Backbone - How do I handle Menu views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm finding it really hard to render some simple views in Backbone, it feels like it's so round-about just to render some HTML and then transition between "pages."  I really just want to render a menu in my home page, and then use the backbone router to switch to the pages it links to without refreshing.

Is this even possible without a corresponding model in the view?  How would I go about it?

Also I don't understand modular js at all.. how would one organize all of this?

Comment: its better to chat about this

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/56529/marionettejs-and-backbonejs-introduce?tab=general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone lets you organize your JS in any way you fancy.
A view doesn't always need a model. If you just want to render a static view, go ahead.
Commonly you create a model which contains your menu pages, and let a view render this model to your html.

Render your menu outside of your content area (just create two toplevel div's), and let your router render pages within that content area. Leaving your menu intact.